# Android emulator launched then closed without connection

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I was initially using VS code and the first two time I was able to launch the emulator and see the default new flutter project app but after the third time whenever I launch the emulator, it will pop out the phone with 'loading state...' then the phone will automatically disappear with the error on VS code displaying

> Failed to launch emulator: Error: Emulator didn't connected within 60
> seconds
>
> Source: Dart (Extension)

I tried launching the emulator through the cmd and it gave me this error

> C:\Users\bob 2\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -list-avds
>
> Nexus_5X_API_27_x86
>
> C:\Users\bob 2\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_27_x86
> HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
> createImpl: failed to create context (EGL_NO_CONTEXT result)

When I launched the emulator from Android Studios it also gave me the same error at the bottom

> createImpl: failed to create context (EGL_NO_CONTEXT result)

I created the emulator some time ago using lollipop on Nexus 5x.

I have since created an emulator Pixel_2_API_26 on oreo from the Android Studio's AVD Manager and that worked fine so far.

I am still curious about what 'createImpl: failed to create context' means.

Comment: Try clear the snapshots and set the emulator to not save snapshot's again. To do this go to "Extended Controls" (three dots outside the emulator) > Snapshots > Settings > Auto-save current state to Quickboot > Set to "No". Now close the emulator, go to C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\<emulator> and delete the snapshots folder

Comment: Thanks for your help. My Pixel 2 device eventually failed as well and the error that the cmd gave me this time was 'WARNING: EGL config mismatch, fallback to default configs'. I deleted the snapshots folder and the emulator started up fine again.